# data.frame to spatial polygone data frame

Tags: rstudio, visualization, polygon, spatial, polygons

I have this data.frame

```
data <- read.table(text="Id            x             y valecolo valecono
1     1  12.18255221  29.406365240        4      990
2     2   9.05893970  20.923087170        4     1090
3     3   1.11192442   2.460411416        0      420
4     4  15.51290096  27.185287490       16     1320
5     5  20.41913438  32.166268590       13     1050
6     6  12.75939095  17.552435030       60     1010
7     7  28.06853355  30.839057830       12     1030
8     8   6.96288868   7.177616682       33     1010
9     9  30.60527190  20.792242110       23      640
10   10  12.07646283   7.658266843       19      810
11   11  10.42878294   5.520913954        0      700
12   12  23.61674977  11.111217320        0      838
13   13  27.16148898  12.259423750       11     1330
14   14  28.00931750   6.258448426       20      777
15   15  20.79999922  -0.000877298        4      630
16   16  21.59999968  -0.005502197       38      830
17   17  19.46122172  -1.229166015        7      740
18   18  28.20370719  -6.305622777       12      660
19   19  29.94840042  -7.192584050        0     1030
20   20  29.28601258 -12.133404940       10      870
21   21   5.88104817  -3.608777319        0     1050
22   22  30.37845976 -26.784308510        0      900
23   23  13.68270042 -12.451253320        0      300
24   24  26.01871530 -26.024342420       22     1330
25   25  20.17735764 -20.829648070       21     1190
26   26   5.04404016  -5.550464740        7     1030
27   27  17.98312114 -26.468988540        0     1200
28   28   8.50660753 -12.957145840        9      850
29   29  10.79633248 -18.938827100       36     1200
30   30  13.36599497 -28.413203870        7     1240
31   31  10.77987946 -28.531459810        0      350
32   32   8.35194396 -24.410755680       28      910
33   33   1.55014408 -12.302725060       10      980
34   34  -0.00388992 -17.899999200       12     1120
35   35  -2.82062504 -16.155620130       12      450
36   36  -4.75903628 -22.962014490       20      920
37   37  -6.07839546 -15.339592840       28      840
38   38 -11.32647798 -24.068047630        0      665
39   39 -11.88138209 -24.245262620       12     1180
40   40 -14.06823800 -25.587589260       36      350
41   41 -10.92180227 -18.461223360        7     1180
42   42 -12.48843186 -20.377660600        0      400
43   43 -18.63696964 -27.415068190       18     1220
44   44 -16.73351789 -23.807549250        0      500
45   45 -22.49024869 -29.944803740        7     1040
46   46 -22.66130064 -27.391018580        0      500
47   47 -15.26565038 -17.866446720       16     1060
48   48 -24.20192852 -23.451155780        0      600
49   49 -21.39663774 -20.089958090        0      750
50   50 -12.33344998  -9.875526199       16      980
51   51 -30.94772590 -22.478895910        0      790
52   52 -24.85783868 -15.225318840       25      720
53   53  -2.44485324  -1.145728097       54      970
54   54 -24.67985433  -7.169018707        4      500
55   55 -30.82457650  -7.398346555        4      750
56   56 -23.56898920  -5.265475270        4      760
57   57  -3.91708603  -0.810208045        0      350
58   58 -26.86563675  -4.251776497        0      440
59   59 -26.64738877  -1.675324623        8      450
60   60  -8.79897138  -0.134558536       11      830
61   61 -21.78250663   1.716077388        0      920
62   62 -28.98396759   6.007465815       24      980
63   63 -34.61607994   8.311853049        8      500
64   64 -25.63850107   7.453677191       15      880
65   65 -22.98762116  11.266290120       11      830
66   66 -33.48522130  19.100848030        0      350
67   67 -25.53096486  16.777135830       21      740
68   68 -18.95412327  15.681238150        0      300
69   69  -8.94874230   8.144324435        0      500
70   70 -10.91433241  10.579099310        4      750
71   71 -13.44807236  14.327310800        0     1090
72   72 -16.24086139  20.940019610        0      500
73   73 -17.51162097  24.111886810        0      940
74   74 -12.47496424  18.363422910        0     1020
75   75 -17.76118016  27.990410510        0      660
76   76  -5.54534556   9.730834410        0      850
77   77 -11.30971858  29.934766840        0      950
78   78 -10.38743785  27.493148220        0      740
79   79  -8.61491396  25.166312360        0      950
80   80  -3.40550077  14.197273530        0      710
81   81  -0.77957621   3.770246702        0      750
82   82  -3.01234325  21.186924550        0     1200
83   83  -2.05241931  32.685624900        0     1200
84   84  -2.26900366  36.128820600        0      970
85   85   0.82954518   5.790885396        0      850
86   86  22.08151130  19.671119440       19      870
87   87  12.60107972  23.864904860        0     1260
88   88   9.78406607  26.163968270        0      600
89   89  11.69995152  33.091322170        0     1090
90   90  20.64705880 -16.439632140        0      840
91   91  24.68314851 -21.314655730        0     1561
92   92  30.33133300 -27.235396100        0     1117
93   93 -26.24691654 -22.405635470        0     1040
94   94 -21.68016500 -24.458519270       10     1000
95   95  -1.57455856 -30.874986140        0      500
96   96 -29.75642086  -5.610894981        0      350
97   97  -3.66771076  26.448084810        0      900
98   98 -26.54457307  29.824419350        0     1050
99   99 -17.90426678  18.751297440        0      200
100 100  10.22894253  -6.274450952        0      880")
```

And I would like to create a visualization with the polygons of thiessen, then colorize the polygons according to their "valecono" value.

I tried this:

```
> library(deldir)
> z <- deldir(x,y,rw=c(-34.51608,30.7052719,-30.774986,36.2288206))
> w <- tile.list(z)
> plot(w, fillcol=data$valecono, close=TRUE)
```

Which seems weird to me, and I'm not sure how R attributed these colors.

Do you have any other suggestions for this case?

I also tried to convert my data.frame in SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, what I did not manage. I tried to convert my data.frame into SpatialPointsDataFrame, which was not a problem, but was not very useful, because I did not find how to convert it then to a SpatialPointsDataFrame.

```
spdf <- SpatialPointsDataFrame(coords = coords, data = data,
                               proj4string = CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
```

I try all this because I think that with a SpatialPointsDataFrame, it would be easier to have this visualization of polygons with colors according to the valecono of the points.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
library(dismo)
coordinates(data) <- ~x + y
v <- voronoi(data) 
spplot(v, "valecolo")
```

With base plot

```
s <- (floor(sort(v$valecono)/400) + 1)
plot(v, col=rainbow(60)[v$valecolo+1])
points(data, cex=s/2, col=gray((1:4)/4)[s])
```

Comment: Thank you, that's perfect! Is it possible to add another variable on the plot with this method? The idea is also to represent the value "valecolo" on the same polygons, maybe with another form (points for example)

Comment: I added an example, using base plot